# Stack Overflow CLI

Tags: app, python, stackoverflow

## SoCLI

[image: PyPI version] [image: Build Status] [image: Collaborizm]

Stack overflow command line written in python. Using SoCLI you can search and browse stack overflow without leaving the terminal. Just use the **socli** command:

[image: SoCLI in action]

### Installation

Supported platforms

- Linux
- Windows
- Mac

Requirements

- python 2+

For Linux

Install **python** and just use **pip** command to install **socli**:

```
sudo apt-get install python python-pip
sudo pip install socli
```

For Windows

[Download and install python](https://www.python.org/downloads/). Don't forget to check the option "Add to path".

Open a command prompt with administrative privileges and use **pip** command to install **socli**:

```
pip install socli
```

Use **easy_install** if your python path have a space in it [Read more:"Failed to create process"](https://github.com/gautamkrishnar/socli/issues/6):

```
easy_install socli
```

For Mac (via homebrew)

Install **python** and **socli**:

```
brew install python
easy_install pip
pip install socli
```

### Updating

Use the command below to update your existing version of **socli** to the newest version, so that you won't miss any features:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade socli
```

### Usage

#### Quick search

Just use **socli** command followed by the search query:

```
socli for loop in python syntax
```

The above command will search for the query "*for loop in python syntax*" and displays the first most voted question in stack overflow with its most voted answer. Pretty quick, right?

#### Interactive search

You can search the stack overflow interactively by using the command below:

```
socli -iq html error 404
```

This will display a list of questions from stack overflow for the query "*html error 404*" and it will allow you to choose any of the question you like interactively. When you chose a question, it will display the complete description of the chosen question with its most voted answer. Now you can browse through all the answers of that questions on stack overflow interactively.

#### Manual search

This will allow you to choose a question number for example:

```
socli -r 2 -q javascript porotype function
```

Will search for "*javascript porotype function*" in stack overflow and displays the second question that contains it.

#### Topic based search

Stack overflow supports topic by using tags. **socli** allows you to query stack overflow based on specific tags.  Just specify the tag via the following command:

```
socli -t javascript -q window.open
```

You can also specify multiple tags, Just separate them with a comma:

```
socli -t javascript,node.js -q window.open
```

See the complete list of tags [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags).

#### New question

If you can't find an answer for your question in stack overflow, **socli** allows you to creata a new question via the web browser. Just type the command below and **socli** will open the new question page of stack overflow in the web browser for you:

```
socli -n
```

#### Syntax:

**socli** has the following syntax

```
Usage: socli [ Arguments] < Search Query >
```

Query

It refers to query to search in stack overflow.

#### Features

These are the amazing features of **socli**:

- Manual Search
- Interactively browse stack overflow using the interactive mode
- Coloured interface
- Question stats view
- Tag support
- Can open the page in a browser
- Can create a new question via the web browser

Please check out the list of [issues](https://github.com/gautamkrishnar/socli/issues).

#### Contributing

If you are willing to contribute to SoCLI project, You are awesome! Just follow the steps below:

1. Fork it!
2. Make a local clone:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/{YOUR_USERNAME}/socli.git
```

3. Switch to the directory: `cd socli`
4. Create your new branch: `git checkout -b feature name`
5. Make necessary changes to this source code
6. Add changes to git index by using `git add --all .`
7. Commit your changes: `git commit -am 'Added new feature'`
8. Push to the branch: `git push`
9. Submit a [new pull request](https://github.com/gautamkrishnar/socli/pull/new) :smile:

#### Contributors

Special thanks to these superheroes:

- [Killbee](https://github.com/kilbee) for making SoCLI colorful [#3](https://github.com/gautamkrishnar/socli/pull/3)
- [Sam Dean](https://github.com/deanWombourne) for adding Macintosh SoCLI installation instructions [#1](https://github.com/gautamkrishnar/socli/pull/1)
- [Plinio89s](https://github.com/Plinio89s) for adding the check for color support [#8](https://github.com/gautamkrishnar/socli/pull/8)
- [nagracks](https://github.com/nagracks) for improving readability of the SoCLI code [#11](https://github.com/gautamkrishnar/socli/pull/11)
- [mwwynne](https://github.com/mwwynne) for adding links to the SoCLI [#13](https://github.com/gautamkrishnar/socli/pull/13)
- [Carlos J. Puga Medina](https://github.com/cpu82) for finding the bug [#11](https://github.com/gautamkrishnar/socli/issues/14) on SoCLI python2 version and for making [SoCLI freshports port](https://www.freshports.org/misc/py-socli/)
- [Jon Ericson](https://github.com/jericson) (*Community Manager, Stack Overflow*) for the PR [#18](https://github.com/gautamkrishnar/socli/pull/18) and letting me know about the Stack overflow attribution policy. Thanks for the [blog post](http://jericson.github.io/2016/08/25/long_tail_docs.html)
- [Ankit Kr. Singh](https://github.com/kumarankit0411) for fixing some typos PR [#21](https://github.com/gautamkrishnar/socli/pull/21) [#23](https://github.com/gautamkrishnar/socli/pull/23)
- [Harsha Alva](https://github.com/aharshac) for fixing windows encoding problem PR [#24](https://github.com/gautamkrishnar/socli/pull/21)
- [Pia Mancini](https://github.com/piamancini) for adding SoCLI to OpenCollective [#27](https://github.com/gautamkrishnar/socli/pull/27)
- [Elliott Beach](https://github.com/e-beach) for improving color support by adding colorama [#29](https://github.com/gautamkrishnar/socli/pull/29)
- [Aditya Tandon](https://github.com/adityatandon007) for the issue [#30](https://github.com/gautamkrishnar/socli/issues/30)
- [Akshatha Nayak](https://github.com/Aksh77) for your first contribution to an open source project. PR [#31](https://github.com/gautamkrishnar/socli/issues/31)

#### Bugs

If you are experiencing any bugs, don’t forget to open a [new issue](https://github.com/gautamkrishnar/socli/issues/new).

#### Thanks

- Thanks to all the existing users of SoCLI.
- Thanks to all upvoters and followers on reddit.
- [impress that girl in the Starbucks by browsing SO with your CLI app XD XD](https://www.reddit.com/r/programmingcirclejerk/comments/4pwil4/impress_that_girl_in_the_starbucks_by_browsing_so/) by [insane0hflex](https://www.reddit.com/user/insane0hflex). Thanks for the post :wink:
- Special thanks to people who wrote about SoCLI on their blogs and websites:

  - [wykop.pl](http://www.wykop.pl/wpis/18286681/python-stackoverflow-interfejs-bo-sciaga-musi-byc-/)
  - [memect.com](http://forum.memect.com/blog/thread/py-2016-06-26/)
  - [pseudoscripter](https://pseudoscripter.wordpress.com/2016/06/28/socli-stack-overflow-command-line-client/)
  - [b.hatena.ne.jp](http://b.hatena.ne.jp/entry/s/github.com/gautamkrishnar/socli)
  - [jericson.github.io](http://jericson.github.io/2016/08/25/long_tail_docs.html)
  - [The really big list of really interesting Open Source projects](https://medium.com/@likid.geimfari/the-list-of-interesting-open-source-projects-2daaa2153f7c#.6qm1v3ioa)
  - [Ostechnix](http://www.ostechnix.com/search-browse-stack-overflow-website-commandline/)
- Tweets:

  - [@cyb3rops](https://twitter.com/cyb3rops/status/747380776350650368)
  - [@pythontrending](https://twitter.com/pythontrending/status/745635512803819521)
- Thanks to my favourite IDE JetBrains PyCharm

Visit https://github.com/gautamkrishnar/socli for more info.